# Как вывести bmp файл на форму без компонента image?

Tags: delphi, графика

Как вывести bmp файл на форму без компонента image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

типа так:

```
var pic:Tbitmap;
begin
pic:=Tbitmap.create;
pic.Loadfromfile('c:\pic.bmp');
form.canvas.draw(pic,x,y);
pic.free;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Вывести его на канвас нужного компонента, например формы